# Setting up CrateDB on an ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, sqlalchemy, cratedb

I've got an ec2 running the CrateDB AMI.  It's in a security group that allows incoming traffic on ports 4200 and 4300.  And it's running under an IAM that allows DescribeInstances.
I've verified this much is working by connecting through the web console and sshing into the instance and using Crash or the python library to run a few queries.

My problem is connecting from a separate ec2.  I am using the same security group and I've tried both the public and internal IPs.  The .connect() just seems to hang.
I feel like I should be providing some kind of credentials but I haven't come across anything in the docs.
Thanks.

Comment: The security group permissions were simply not refreshed somewhere either in the instance or the python console.  Closing python, logging out and logging back fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to connect with telnet to port 4200. If this isn't possible - it's most likely an issue with your EC2 security group configuration.

You also might want to check whether iptables is running on the machine and blocking traffic.